# How to use chrome-aws-lambda module with AWS lambda functions?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, chrome-aws-lambda

I am trying to generate pdf from HTML using chrome-aws-lambda by node.js lambda function.
I created a Layer using this [manual](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda#aws-lambda-layer). Also, I tried to use existing [layer](https://github.com/shelfio/chrome-aws-lambda-layer) with my function but I always get an error: `Cannot read property 'puppeteer' of undefined`.
My handler looks like:

```
import chromium from 'chrome-aws-lambda';    
export const handler: Handler = async (event: AppsyncEvent) => {
      ...
      try {
        browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
          args: chromium.args,
          defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
          executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
          headless: chromium.headless
        });
    ....
      } finally {
    ....
      }
    }
```

webpack settings in serverless.yml

```
webpack:
    webpackConfig: ../webpack.config.js
    includeModules:
      packagePath: '../package.json'
      forceInclude:
        - source-map-support
      forceExclude:
        - aws-sdk
        - chrome-aws-lambda
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: ['chrome-aws-lambda'],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader'}
        ]
    },
    plugins: []
}
```

Could you help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

So, the problem was with imports.
I changed

```
import chromium from 'chrome-aws-lambda'
```

to

```
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda')
```

the error is gone